# How To Structure Array Into UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsarray

I have an array with the following format:

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
 [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"number",@"name",@"date",@"about",nil],
 [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"number",@"name",@"date",@"about",nil],
 [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"number",@"name",@"date",@"about",nil],
 [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"number",@"name",@"date",@"about",nil],
 nil];
```

I want to structure this data to load into my tableView.

Each row of the tableview should correspond to each row of the array, then the title of each cell should correspond to the subarray objectAtIndex 2 for the name.

Comment: It seems to me that this code is already 'structured' for a `UITableView`.  Are you looking for the code to implement the creation of the `UITableViewCell`s?

Comment: it looks like you're doing this the wrong way... you ned to be more specific about how you want the tableview to appear

Comment: Yes, i guess so, looking to setup the cells.  Something like cell.textlabel.text = [array object at what?]] Because its an array inside an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your array is named `myData`:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
  // Return the number of sections.
  return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  // Return the number of rows in the section.
  return [myData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
  }

  // Configure the cell...
  NSArray *obj = [myData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  cell.textLabel.text = (NSString*)[obj objectAtIndex:1]; //note: 0=>number; 1=>name,..

  return cell;
}
```

In favor of reusability, I would suggest to replace the subarrays with NSDictionaries so that you can get e.g. the name by calling `[dict objectForKey:@"name"]`.